# R-Python : how to eliminate specific rows and columns?

Tags: python, r

Take this **R** demo as an example :

```
df <- matrix(1:100, nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
```

*df* :

```
> df
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1   11   21   31   41   51   61   71   81    91
 [2,]    2   12   22   32   42   52   62   72   82    92
 [3,]    3   13   23   33   43   53   63   73   83    93
 [4,]    4   14   24   34   44   54   64   74   84    94
 [5,]    5   15   25   35   45   55   65   75   85    95
 [6,]    6   16   26   36   46   56   66   76   86    96
 [7,]    7   17   27   37   47   57   67   77   87    97
 [8,]    8   18   28   38   48   58   68   78   88    98
 [9,]    9   19   29   39   49   59   69   79   89    99
[10,]   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100
```

Now I want to eliminate `2:8` rows and `3:7` columns, so I did:

```
> eliminated.rows <- 2:8
> eliminated.cols <- 3:7
> df <- df[-eliminated.rows, -eliminated.cols]
```

Then I got what I want:

```
> df
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1   11   71   81   91
[2,]    9   19   79   89   99
[3,]   10   20   80   90  100
```

Question is :

**How to achieve my goal with Python ?**

**EDIT:**

To be specific, if I got lists of rows and columns to be eliminated, like `eliminated_rows = list(), eliminated_cols = list()`, and I want result `df = df[-eliminated_rows, -eliminated_cols]` with python.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want a solution with pandas dataframes or numpy matrix? Your example is a bit confusing as you are naming a matrix, *df*.

Comment: Apologize, it's `pandas DataFrame` actually, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: With pandas: [check here](http://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_dropping_column_and_rows.html)

Comment: I didn't find the proper solution in the page you given, but the answer provided by  @Chirayu Chamoli works for me. It seems that Python may need a lot more operations on DataFrame or Matrix comparing to R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 10)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))
row_i= df.index.isin(range(1,8))
col_i=df.index.isin(range(2,7))
df.iloc[~row_i,~col_i]
```

Be careful of the index as it starts from 0 in python.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It works, thank you so much for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (careful with the indices):

```
Try this:

matrix = []
for row in range(0,100,10):
    column = [i for i in range(row,row+10)]
    matrix.append(column)
columns_to_remove = [1,2,8]
rows_to_remove = [4,5,9]
for i in rows_to_remove:
    matrix.pop(i)
for remaining_rows in matrix:
    for remove_column in matrix:
        matrix.pop(matrix[remaining_rows][remove_column])
```

Comment: Is `for` really necessary ?  Cause I don't think this is the right way to do it, thanks for help.

Comment: probably not, i'm not too familiar with Pandas or NumPy but I know this will work

Answer (score 0):

After checking [select data from data frame](https://community.modeanalytics.com/python/tutorial/pandas-dataframe/),I think this solution may be easier to understand :

E.g. `3 * 3` DataFrame, eliminate rows `1,2`, columns `0,1`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 9, size = (3, 3)))

#print df

eliminated_rows = [1, 2] #rows to eliminated
eliminated_cols = [0, 1] #cols to eliminated

range_rows = range(0, df.shape[0])
remaining_rows = [row for row in range_rows if row not in eliminated_rows]

range_cols = range(0, df.shape[1])
remaining_cols = [col for col in range_cols if col not in eliminated_cols]

df = df.iloc[remaining_rows, remaining_cols]

#print df
```

> Original DataFrame `3 * 3`:

```
   0  1  2
0  4  3  3
1  2  8  7
2  5  1  7
```

> Result :

```
   2
0  3
```